# How to send some custom tokens with MetaMask API?

Tags: ethereum, metamask

It seems the example code on the MetaMask documentation page, sends ETH only. How should I customize the sample code to send some custom tokens?

```
const transactionParameters = {
  nonce: '0x00', // ignored by MetaMask
  gasPrice: '0x09184e72a000', // customizable by user during MetaMask confirmation.
  gas: '0x2710', // customizable by user during MetaMask confirmation.
  to: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000', // Required except during contract publications.
  from: ethereum.selectedAddress, // must match user's active address.
  value: '0x00', // Only required to send ether to the recipient from the initiating external account.
  data:
    '0x7f7465737432000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600057', // Optional, but used for defining smart contract creation and interaction.
  chainId: '0x3', // Used to prevent transaction reuse across blockchains. Auto-filled by MetaMask.
};

// txHash is a hex string
// As with any RPC call, it may throw an error
const txHash = await ethereum.request({
  method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
  params: [transactionParameters],
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A transaction sending an [ERC-20](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md) token needs to have the token contract as the recipient (the `to` field), and the `data` field containing encoded instructions to execute its `transfer()` function along with address of the token receiver and amount.

```
const transactionParameters = {
    from: accounts[0],
    to: tokenContractAddress,
    data: getDataFieldValue(tokenRecipientAddress, tokenAmount),
};
await ethereum.request({
    method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
    params: [transactionParameters],
});
```

You can use for example the web3js library ([docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.0/web3-eth-abi.html#encodefunctioncall)) to encode the `data` field value. The `transfer()` function is standardized - so assuming the token contract follows the standard, it's going to be the same for any token contract.

```
function getDataFieldValue(tokenRecipientAddress, tokenAmount) {
    const web3 = new Web3();
    const TRANSFER_FUNCTION_ABI = {"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"};
    return web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionCall(TRANSFER_FUNCTION_ABI, [
        tokenRecipientAddress,
        tokenAmount
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For a cleaner version of Petr's solution using the encodeABI function.

```
await window.ethereum
    .request({
      method: "eth_sendTransaction",
      params: [
        {
          from: accounts[0],
          to: TOKEN_CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
          data: tokenContract.methods
            .transfer(receiverAddress, amount)
            .encodeABI(),
        },
      ],
    })
    .then((result) =>  console.log(result))
    .catch((error) => console.error(error));
```